How Can I Deploy a Selenium Script That Runs Every 3 Days?
I’ve built a web scraping script using python and selenium, this script is basically a telegram bot that send a latest update on something.
I want this script to run every 3 days. How to deploy it?
I tried multiple solutions but every time I face a problem on executing the chrome driver..

Have you thought about cron or it's equivalent on Windows?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You may use Jenkins to schedule a job that runs every 3 days.

These are good options. You can make this more or less complicated, depending on what you want/need to do. I have had a lot of success deploying Selenium scrapers in Docker containers on ECS (https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). ECS jobs can be easily scheduled and this is a cost-effective option for deploying your crawlers in the cloud. Alternatively, a persistent EC2 instance might be a good option.
